# Is setting objects in the session that already exist useful in a Java web app?

Tags: java, session

In our Java web application which uses Struts 1, we have a lot of code that essentially does this:

```
HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
MyObject myObject = session.getAttribute(MY_OBJECT_KEY);

//code that mutates myObject - setting properties or whatever

session.setAttribute(MY_OBJECT_KEY, myObject);
```

My question: Is the last line, session.setAttribute(..) necessary? It seems pointless to me - 'myObject' and 'session.getAttribute(..)' refer to the same location in memory, right? So re-setting the attribute in the session should not be required? Does this do anything I am not aware of? The object does not implement HttpSessionBindingListener which is mentioned in the documentation.

I feel like I need to double check because this is done all over this app and I certainly don't want to break anything just because I am cleaning up code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "mutate".  If "mutate" in this context means you changed properties, but not the instance, then no, you don't need to `setAttribute` at the end.

`myObject` is a *reference* to the underlying object.  The session has its own reference.  They both point to the same underlying object, so you'd be changing properties on the same instance.

Now, if you do

`myObject = new MYObject();`

THEN you need to pass the new object to the session.  In this case, your reference `myObject` now points to a different instance than the session's reference.

Note, why not write a unit test and test it out?

Comment: Thank you, sometimes I just need to be told what I already know. My confusion was because of a comment in the source code which seemed to indicate session.setAttribute was doing something it does not. You are also right about the unit test..

Comment: AFAIK, `setAttribute` doesn't do anything wonky.  From the javadoc "Binds an object to this session, using the name specified. If an object of the same name is already bound to the session, the object is replaced."

Answer (score 0):

@emulcahy,
I know this is an old post. I just stumbled on this while researching on Servlet listeners. Did you find out the reason for those "redundant" setAttribute(s)?

I am wondering if they were added to trigger events in Servlet listeners.  You may want to check if there are any object(s) that implement HttpSessionAttributeListener or HttpSessionBindingListener. They may be used to log information in those session variables. Just a thought. If you already solved your problem, please ignore this message.